# Morphia disable loading of @referenced entities

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I have 2 collections.

```
@Entity
public class TypeA {
    //other fields
    @Reference
    List<TypeB> typeBList;
}

@Entity
public class TypeB{
  //Fields here.
}
```

After a save operation, sample TypeA document is as below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fda48c60b200ee765367b1"),
    "typeBList" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "TypeB",
            "$id" : ObjectId("58fda48c60b200ee765367ac")
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "TypeB",
            "$id" : ObjectId("58fda48c60b200ee765367af")
        }
    ]
}
```

When I query for TypeA , morphia eagerly loads all the TypeB entites, which I dont want.

I tried using the @Reference(lazy = true). But no help.

So is there a way I can write a query using morphia where I only get all $ids inside the typeBList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a list ob ObjectIds instead of a `@Reference` and manually fetch those entries when you need them.

Lazy will only load referenced entities on demand, but since you are trying to access something in that list, they will be loaded.

Personal opinion: `@Reference` looks great when you start, but its use can quickly cause issues. Don't build a schema with lots of references — MongoDB is not a relational database.

Comment: Thanks @xeraa for suggestion. @Reference(idOnly = true) on typeBList will be able todo this.

Comment: Isn't that only related to storage? At least if the docs can be trusted: https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/annotations/#reference